# Grouping sum by user provided field name in graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler, qgis-expression

I want to sum and group some percentages as a part of a model in order to check whether the percentages are exactly 100, or if there is a small rounding error.

When using the field calculator outside the model, `sum("percentage field","group field")` works flawlessly as usual.

Since the name of the group field may change between summed up layers (the percentage field is created within the model), I want the user to provide said field name and use that input in my expression, giving me `sum("percentage field",@user_input)`. This expression doesn't group the sum, but sums up all values - and I can't figure out how to make it work as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to change your formula to `precalculated value` and then make a string representation of your formula like:

```
'sum("percentage field",'  ||  @user_input ||  ')'
```