"Extract by Expression" works manually, but not in model
I have a QGIS project (v 3.34.0) where I run a model to calculate distances from all building facades to the nearest road. The last step in the model is to extract only those line features (the calculated distances building->road) that do not cross over a building (i.e. I only want to keep the distance from a building's front facade to the road, and not the distance from a building's back facade.).
For that, I run "Extract by Expression" with the following expression:NOT overlay_crosses('buildings_lines_exploded'). When I run it manually, it works fine, but when I put the same in the QGIS model (which works fine otherwise), I only receive an empty output. Why does this happen? I put "Snap geometries to layer" as parent algorithm for the Extraction Algorithm.
(I wanted to use "Extract by Location" first, but it doesn't seem to offer the option to use the negated form of the argument, only "crosses" etc.)

Maybe this is similar to a problem I had: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/473942/grouping-sum-by-user-provided-field-name-in-graphical-modeler please try that solution.

Check https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/379549/107424

Thanks @MrXsquared, that (using building_lines_exploded_OUTPUT) solved my problem! See here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/469257/242100
